# Installshield changing <clear /> to <clear></clear> and breaking the service

Tags: installshield

My source xml looks like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="StrConn" providerName="SQLNCLI10" 
connectionString="Server=dbserver;Database=db;User Id=user;Password=pass;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Notice the seemingly innocent `<clear />` tag.

Once I've imported this xml, and made changes to the xml file i.e: the connection string. All single tags in the document like `<add />` or `<clear />` are rewritten to long form eg: `<clear></clear>` and this prevents my service / app from even running.

It seems crazy since ultimately it seems like valid XML, but yeah it dies with an unknown fault exception, but when replacing the clear tags to all be `<clear />` and not `<clear ></clear>` it works.

How can I prevent installshield from transforming these tags?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 'update xml' feature?  Try using the 'udpate text file' instead. That's a bit ugly to use for xml files but it works (we've been using it before the update xml feature was introduced)